# Number of terms in a Polynomial Expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For a binomial $(a + b)^n$, the number of terms is n + 1.

For a trinomial $(a + b + c)^n$, the number of terms is $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{(2)}$.

For a multinomial $(a + b + c +d)^n$, the number of terms is $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{(6)}$.

I'm guessing that for $(a + b + c + d + e)^n$, the number of terms formula would include $(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)$ on the numerator but I don't know what should be its denominator.

**Question:**

1. What is the number of terms for $(a + b + c + d + e)^n$?
2. Do we have a general formula for the number of terms of a polynomial expansion?
3. What if the given is $(a^2 + a + b)^n$, can I still use the formula $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{(2)}$.when 2 terms in the expansion has the same variable?
4. What if the given is $(a + b + Constant)^n$, would the constant affect the number of terms?

Comment: For the first few problems, you want to count the number of solutions of the equation $d_1+d_2+...+d_k=n$ with $d_i\geq 0$ and integer. Each solution represents a term $x_1^{d_1}x_2^{d_2}...x_k^{d_k}$ of $(x_1+x_2+...+x_k)^n$. [This is a counting argument used for that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: For (4) you need to count the number of solutions of $d_1+d_2\leq n$, $d_1,d_2\geq 0$. This problem can also be reduced to the previous, by adding a slack variable $d_1+d_2+s=n$, $s\geq0$.

Comment: For (3) you can do it in stages. Firs, there is one term of $(A+b)^n$. for each power of $b$: $1,b,b^2,...,b^n$. But $b^k$ gets multiplied by $(a^2+a)^{n-k}=a^{n-k}(a+1)^{n-k}$. You can count the number of terms of this one $(n-k)$. Then add this number for each possible $k$.

Answer (score 3):

For a multinomial $(\sum_{i=1}^m x_i)^n$, the number of terms are ${{n+m-1} \choose {m-1}}$ or ${{n+m-1} \choose {n}}$

This is the same as n apples in m baskets. The combinations are ${{n+m-1} \choose 
{m-1}}$ or ${{n+m-1} \choose {n}}$

Comment: $^{n+m-1}c_{m-1}$ is slightly non-standard notation. Please consider using $_a C_b$ or $\binom{a}{b}$ instead.