# How many collected terms are in the expansion of $(x+y+z)^{10} (w+x+y+z)^2$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem, multinomial-theorem

How many collected terms are in the expansion of $(x+y+z)^{10} (w+x+y+z)^2$?

Hi, I'm trying to solve this problem as study material for discrete mathematics and I'm not quite sure how. I got 235 terms by plugging it into Wolfram Alpha, but I'm don't really know how to get the answer. I feel like combinatorics and the binomial theorem can be applied in some way as per the curriculum in my class, but that's about it.

Comment: Welcome Gift G. : $(x+y+z)^5$ has as many terms as $3 a_i^5+6a_i^4(a_j+a_k)+6a_i^3(a_j^2+a_k^2)+3a_i^3a_ja_k+3a_i^2a_ja_k^2$ so $3+6+6+3+3=21$ terms. It follows that a bound for the total collected terms
$$(b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_{21})^2(w+x+y+z)^2\le \left(21+\binom{21}{2}\right)\cdot\left(4+\binom{4}{2}\right)=231\cdot10=2310$$ What remains to do is to look at similar terms in this multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, observe that:

$$(x+y+z)^{10}(w+x+y+z)^2=w^2(x+y+z)^{10}+2w(x+y+z)^{11}+(x+y+z)^{12};$$

and notice that the total number of terms of $(x+y+z)^{10}(w+x+y+z)^2$ is the sum of those of $w^2(x+y+z)^{10}, 2w(x+y+z)^{11}$, and $(x+y+z)^{12}$ because of the distinct powers of $w$.

Hence the answer is $\begin{pmatrix}
12  \\
2  \\
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
13  \\
2  \\
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
14  \\
2  \\
\end{pmatrix}=235.$ For more information you can read [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2768522/number-of-terms-in-a-polynomial-expansion) and [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).